# Will I be able to read PDFs in Cyrillic on Kindle (classic)?

Tags: kindle, pdf, fonts

I have many PDF's in Russian, with embedded fonts. Will I be able to read them on my Kindle (classic) device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Kindle (classic) has no problem with displaying Cyrillic characters in PDFs.

Here is the proof:

[image: Image of Cyrillic text on a classic Kindle device]

Comment: You can probably mark your own answer as correct in this case.